# Multiple boxplots in SAS

Tags: statistics, sas

I have this data set and I would like to make all boxplots of the 9 input variables to appear on the same plot, despite that they are in different scales. Could you please tell me if there is an easy way to accomplish this?

I am a novice SAS user so I would appreciate some advice. Thank you.

```
data raw;
input ID$ Family DistRd Cotton Maize Sorg Millet Bull Cattle Goats;
datalines;
FARM1 12 80 1.5 1 3 0.25 2 0 1
FARM2 54 8 6 4 0 1 6 32 5
FARM3 11 13 0.5 1 0 0 0 0 0
FARM4 21 13 2 2.5 1 0 1 0 5
FARM5 61 30 3 5 0 0 4 21 0
FARM6 20 70 0 2 3 0 2 0 3
FARM7 29 35 1.5 2 0 0 0 0 0
FARM8 29 35 2 3 2 0 0 0 0
FARM9 57 9 5 5 0 0 4 5 2
FARM10 23 33 2 2 1 0 2 1 7
FARM11 13 9 0.5 2 2 0 0 0 0
FARM12 15 9 2 2 2 0 0 0 0
FARM13 27 3 1.5 0 2 1 0 0 1
FARM14 28 5 2 0.5 2 2 2 0 5
FARM15 52 5 7 1 7 0 4 11 3
FARM16 12 10 2 2.5 3 0 0 0 0
FARM17 25 30 1 1 4 0 2 0 5
FARM18 5 3 1 0 1 0.5 0 0 3
FARM19 45 30 4.5 1 1 0 6 13 20
FARM20 6 7 1 1 1 1 2 0 5
FARM21 17 8 1.5 0.5 1.5 0.25 0 0 2
FARM22 22 6 3 2 3 1 3 0 2
FARM23 43 40 7 3 3 0.5 6 2 3
FARM24 66 36 0 0.5 5 5 0 0 0
FARM25 15 3 1 0 1.5 0.5 1 0 1
FARM26 26 5 2 1.5 2 2 1 0 0
FARM27 31 5 1.5 1 3 2 2 0 0
FARM28 37 2 3 2 3 5 3 0 5
FARM29 81 2 8 4 4 12 7 8 13
FARM30 14 10 0 0.5 3 1 0 0 0
FARM31 20 7 2 1 4 3 2 0 5
FARM32 26 7 2 1 2 2 2 0 2
FARM33 12 10 0.5 1 3 1 0 0 0
FARM34 18 35 4 3 3 3 4 0 0
FARM35 11 29 1 0.5 3 2 2 0 2
FARM36 50 29 5 3 5 4 4 8 4
FARM37 7 9 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
FARM38 26 9 2 1 3 0 0 0 0
FARM39 19 33 1 1.5 0 4 2 0 0
FARM40 43 33 3 3 4 7 4 3 0
FARM41 18 12 3 0 1 1 2 1 1
FARM42 64 20 3 5 2 2 4 0 6
FARM43 61 25 9 7 3 8 4 17 0
FARM44 18 3 0.5 0.5 2 2 0 0 4
FARM45 11 2 0.5 0 1.5 1.5 1 1 0
FARM46 30 3 4 2 4 0 4 2 0
FARM47 16 1.5 2 0.5 2 2 2 2 0
FARM48 46 1 0.75 1 3 2 0 0 2
FARM49 18 2 1.5 0.5 2 2 2 0 2
FARM50 81 3 12 1.5 10 8 11 14 15
FARM51 15 0 1.5 1.5 2.5 0 1 0 0
FARM52 26 11 3.5 2 4 0 2 2 2
FARM53 10 11 0 0 1.5 0 0 0 0
FARM54 40 12 5 3 6 1 8 17 10
FARM55 82 4 11 7 5 0.5 8 5 0
FARM56 40 5.5 6 4 2.5 1 3 0 2
FARM57 29 8 3 2 4 2 0 0 2
FARM58 23 5 5 4 3 1 1 0 0
FARM59 53 4 0 3 0 3 6 0 0
FARM60 57 3.5 9 8 0 0 10 23 0
FARM61 23 4 2 2 0.5 4 2 0 0
FARM62 9 31 2 2 0 2 1 0 0
FARM63 22 35 3 2 3 0 5 6 1
FARM64 25 35 3 1 2.5 0 4 8 10
FARM65 20 0 1.5 1 3 0 1 6 0
FARM66 27 41 1.1 0.25 1.5 1.5 0 3 1
FARM67 30 19 2 2 4 1 2 0 5
FARM68 77 18 8 4 6 4 6 8 6
FARM69 13 100 0.5 0.5 0 1 0 0 4
FARM70 24 100 2 3 0 0.5 3 14 10
FARM71 29 90 2 1.5 1.5 1.5 2 0 2
FARM72 57 90 10 7 0 1.5 7 8 7
;
run;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to transpose the values and use a group= statement.

Steps

1 Sort by ID

2 Transpose the data

3 Adjust the labels for display

4 Plot with PROC SGPLOT

```
proc sort data=raw;
by id;
run;

proc transpose data=raw out=raw_t;
by id;
run;

data raw_t;
set raw_t;
label _name_ = "Variable";
label col1 = "Value";
run;

ods html;
title "My Box Plot";
proc sgplot data=raw_t;
vbox col1 / group=_name_ ;
run;
ods html close;
```

Produces:
[image]